# Is this proof on the Schur decomposition wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, triangularization, schur-decomposition

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition

In this wikipedia article, the proof of the Schur decomposition is as follows:
For a given eigenvalue $ \lambda_i$, we obtain orthonormal eigenvectors associated with it, which we use to diagonalise the $dim(V_\lambda)   \times dim(V_\lambda$) submatrix restricted to this eigenspace. Then we continue to diagonalise successive eigenspaces until we obtain a fully upper-triangulated matrix.

However, the proof fails to mention the corner case where the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue ($ dim\ ker(A-\lambda_i I)$) fails to be as large as its algebraic multiplicity (power k of factor $ (\lambda-\lambda_i)^k$ in characterisitc polynomial). This basically means that there are more $\lambda_i $s that could appear in the diagonal than there are orthonormal eigenvectors to diagonalise it.  In Jordan normal form, we resort to constructing orthonormal generalised eigenvectors to put the matrix in a nice form. In the wikipedia proof on the other hand, it is not stipulated how to obtain such orthonormal eigenvectors to diagonalise (or at least put in upper-triangular form) the last m diagonals which do not have eigenvalues associated with them.

I'm wondering if the proof is incomplete or if I'm missing something out.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The multiplicity is irrelevant. All that matters is that there is **some** subspace of $\dim \ge 1$ on which $A$ is scalar multiplication.

Comment: @copper.hat   Alright, I'll buy that. Does that mean that we restrict the remaining part of the matrix $A_{22}$ to the orthogonal complement of $V_\lambda$, even though $ker(A_{22}) =/= V_\lambda$? Yes, in fact, $V_{\lambda}^{\bot} \cap ker(A_{22})$ might not be $\varnothing$. Alright, then all that's left is to prove that every linear operator has at least one eigenvalue.

Comment: The latter follows from the fundamental theorem of algebra.